# Run-time error '9' Sub FillItUp

Tags: vba, excel

I get am getting an error on line

```
entries(pos) = oldEntry
```

in

```
If newEntry <> oldEntry Then
            entries(pos) = oldEntry
            oldEntry = newEntry
            pos = pos + 1
        End If
```

It says Subscript out of range. >.<

Full Code:

```
 Sub FillItUp()
        Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
        Dim oldEntry, newEntry As String
        Dim entries(12), toCompare
        Dim pos As Integer
        lastRow = Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = Sheets(1).Range("A6").CurrentRegion.columns.Count
        pos = 0

        toCompare = Array("Avocent", "Channel", "Enterprise", "Industrial", _
                          "Service", "Telecom", "Light Industrial")

        oldEntry = Sheets(1).Range("E7").Value
        entries(pos) = oldEntry

        pos = pos + 1

        For i = 7 To lastRow
            newEntry = Sheets(1).Range("E" & i).Value

            If newEntry <> oldEntry Then
                entries(pos) = oldEntry
                oldEntry = newEntry
                pos = pos + 1
            End If

            If i = lastRow Then
                entries(pos) = newEntry

            End If
```

Comment: What is the value of `pos` when it crashes?  More than 12?

Comment: @YowE3K I fail to imagine another answer than *Yes*...

Comment: @A.S.H - No, the answer **could** be "No" (although I doubt it) - we aren't seeing all the code, so there could be a later statement which says `pos = pos - 200`.

Comment: @YowE3K what do u mean "what is the value of pos when it crashes?"

Comment: @nubcoder17 - when it crashes, and you go to debug, hover your mouse over the variable `pos` in your code and it should tell you the current value.  We are betting that the answer will be 13 (i.e. a number bigger than 12) because your array is dimensioned from 0 To 12.  That then raises the next question of why is your array only dimensioned to a maximum of 12?  Is that the maximum number of values you would expect could possibly be being put into the `entries` array?  It's possible a `ReDim` will fix the issue (which is what A.S.H was suggesting to me in his last comment).

Comment: @YowE3K yes, its value is 13. so, which block of code should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell whether you need to increase the initial size of your array (perhaps because you now have more possible values than you used to), or whether your data is wrong (possibly because it is meant to be sorted but isn't) and would (if it was correct) occupy less than 12 positions in your array.

The following code will make the array dynamic, and increase the dimensions every time a new value is found.

```
Sub FillItUp()
        Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
        Dim oldEntry, newEntry As String
        Dim entries(), toCompare
        Dim pos As Integer
        lastRow = Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = Sheets(1).Range("A6").CurrentRegion.columns.Count
        pos = 0
        ReDim entries(0 To 0)

        toCompare = Array("Avocent", "Channel", "Enterprise", "Industrial", _
                          "Service", "Telecom", "Light Industrial")

        oldEntry = Sheets(1).Range("E7").Value
        entries(pos) = oldEntry

        pos = pos + 1

        For i = 7 To lastRow
            newEntry = Sheets(1).Range("E" & i).Value

            If newEntry <> oldEntry Then
                ReDim Preserve entries(0 To pos)
                entries(pos) = oldEntry
                oldEntry = newEntry
                pos = pos + 1
            End If

            If i = lastRow Then
                ReDim Preserve entries(0 To pos)
                entries(pos) = newEntry

            End If
```

Note that you will need to change any subsequent code you have that uses the content of `entries` in order to allow for the fact that you now have `0 To pos` entries in the array, and not `0 To 12`.

Comment: @YoewE3K thanks man. both your code and janiashish code works. Also, I have more questions for u guys because I don't realy know anything about excel vba. im gonna post more questions, so please stay with me :) haha!

Comment: @nubcoder17 - Hopefully someone will answer them, but my lunch break is just about over so I won't have a chance to look at them until I get home this evening.  (Unless I get bored with work and sneak a peak at SO to keep me awake.)

Comment: you're my hero :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the index of array as well in the IF statement. Example code below:

```
If newEntry <> oldEntry AND (pos >= 0 AND pos < 12) Then
    entries(pos) = oldEntry
    oldEntry = newEntry
    pos = pos + 1
End If
```

Comment: @ jainashish my applogies, your code is correct. I just asked my boss and its correct. thanks a lot.